# Select last child when odd, 2 last childs when even

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

I'm in a situation where the number of elements shown is variable, and I need a strange solution that I'm not able to achieve, I even doubt if it's achievable only with CSS.

I need to select the last child if my number of elements is odd, and the last 2 children if the number of elements is even.

I've been trying with `nth-last-child`, `:not(:nth-last-child())`, odd and even, but never got a good solution.

Does anyone have any idea/advice about this issue besides adding a class "odd" like on HTML tables?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is one way...

```css
.wrap div:last-child,
.wrap div:nth-last-of-type(-n+2):not(:nth-child(even)) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrap">
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This just selects the last two elements when you have an even number of elements, but doesn't select anything when there is an odd number of elements. The answer below is the correct one.

Comment: The demo works in every browser I have tested @steve, and has done for the past 7+ years. Can I ask what browser you are using?

Comment: Using FF 106.0.2, which is the latest version for my distro (Mint). Here's what I see https://snipboard.io/zKWk7e.jpg

Comment: Apologies @Turnip - It may help for me to scroll the bottom of the list into view! This certainly works.

Answer (score 18):

You can use CSS like so:

```
li:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
    /* Last child AND odd */
    background: red;
}

li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd),
li:last-child:nth-child(even) {
    /* Before last child AND odd */
    /* Last child AND even */
    background: green;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hw0ehrhy/

Comment: This code works also perfectly!! But the answer is shorter, which is  one point better. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: For my need, this one nailed it!

Answer (score -5):

Absolutely it can be done, with pure CSS. See the complete code below (odd child, last child red; even childs, last 2 childs green)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#but1').click(function(){
            var count = $('p').length; 
            if (count%2!=0) {$('div>p:last-child').css('background','red');}
            else {$('div>p:last-child').css('background','green');alert(count);
                $('div>p:nth-last-child(2)').css('background','green');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id=but1>Click</button>
<div>
<p>This is one.     </p>
<p> This is two.    </p>
<p> This is three.  </p>
<p> This is four.   </p>
<p> This is five.   </p>
<p> This is six.    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Enjoy, the coding ;)

Comment: How is this "pure CSS"?

Comment: Yep, jquery involved! But, did it mean -1 repo! :(

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a only css solution, no js or jq. Thanks for your answer anyway!