# In a 3 column grid of a varying number of elements, how to select only the elements that appear on the last line using CSS

Tags: css

Image example: [3 column grid with 1, 2 or 3 elements on the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzBU5.png)

Is it possible to select only the elements that appear on the last line using only CSS? The number of elements in the grid will vary. Here is an example of how to do it with a 2 column grid: [Select last child when odd, 2 last childs when even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770736/select-last-child-when-odd-2-last-childs-when-even)

```
<h2>6 elements</h2>
<ul>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
</ul>
<h2>7 elements</h2>
<ul>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
</ul>
<h2>8 elements</h2>
<ul>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li>hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">hello ------</li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example of the HTML on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rm9te941/

Thanks

Comment: Welome to stackoverflow please read on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ; We can't guess your code structure!

Comment: I think it depends on the HTML you have. Make a demo with what you got.

Comment: Thank Aaron, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also said 'No' but also 'Why not?'

You just have to select all the elements after the element that is `nth-child(3n)` but also `:nth-last-child(-n + 4)` which means:

> Every element that is both after an element that is a multiple of three and
>   is in the last three elements

```
li:nth-last-child(-n + 4):nth-child(3n) ~ li {
  background: #000;
}
```

I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/761so6z5/)

The funny thing is that this will work for **every** number of columns providing you change `3` with the number of your columns.

Comment: I retired my answer, I took 10mins to write, only to find out I missed something real easy! Well done!

Comment: That's really great, thanks for your help. Really versatile too, as you can use it for any number of columns. Cheers.