# Adding border-bottom to dynamic Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating columns dynamically using Bootstrap. I have a for loop that creates the following columns:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 inspection-category-col">
  <div class="media inspection-category"> 
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="media-body inspection-category-media-body"> 
      <h3 class="media-heading inspection-category-media-heading">{{ item.title }}</h3>
      <span class="inspection-category-media-content"> 
        {{ item.description }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a border-bottom between each column, but since I don't know the number of columns I need to handle the following logic:

```
if screen md/lg && count(cols) > 2 && not last one or two cols
  add border-bottom
else if screen xs && not last col
  add border bottom
else 
  do nothing
```

I'm not sure the best way to handle this. Ideally through CSS, but I'm not sure how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given your logic, we can break this down into smaller steps.

First, screen size. For this we use a css media query. Here, I'm defining a large screen to be over 600px wide and a small to be unde 600px wide. you can change this to suit your needs.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  /* large code here */
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* small code here */
}
```

Then we need the border logic, firstly for the larger screens. Here I assume they all have a class of myColumn.

```
.myColumn:nth-last-of-type(n+3) {
    border-bottom:1px solid black
}
```

:nth-last-of-type selects the number in the brackets amount of elements from the end of a list. n+3 means select from the 2nd element in the list, i.e., skip two then select the third element onwards from the end if they have class myColumn

use

```
.myColumn:nth-last-of-type(n+2) {
    border-bottom:1px solid black
}
```

for your smaller screens.

You can mess about with the selectors more [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)

You can read more about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Thanks, @Deep! This works great for the small code, but doesn't work quite right for the large. In my example there are 3 different columns: two on the top and one on the bottom. There is a border-bottom below the first col, but not the second.

Comment: Using :nth-last-of-type(n+2) would work for the above, case, but not for a case where there are only two columns.

Comment: @MollyHarper I must have misunderstood your logic as that seems to work exactly as I intended, border bottom on all but the last 2 columns, could you explain again what you want?

Comment: Hey @Deep, I may not have explained it well. Here's a screenshot of what I want it to look like: http://tinypic.com/r/51x9c4/9. Basically, a border-bottom under each if count(cols) > 2 && not last one or two cols.

Comment: @MollyHarper so if there were 6, 4 would have a border, 2 wouldnt?
5, 4 would 1 wouldnt?
4, 2 would 2 wouldnt?
3 , 2 would 1 wouldnt?

Comment: Yep, you have it exactly!

Comment: In which case, this question is a possible duplicate
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770736/select-last-child-when-odd-2-last-childs-when-even